# Why would a motion sensor cause the light to flicker?

Tags: wiring

I recently installed a motion sensor light and was called back because the light was "flickering" at half brightness rather than staying on brightly.
I tested the power and found good voltage, but when I put my tester to ohm meter and touched the white wire and the conduit, it showed that there is a connection between the two.
At the panel there is no separation between the ground bus bar and the neutral bus bar. Touching the two with ohm meter shows the same as when I touch the neutral and the conduit - a direct path between the two.
I am unsure if there is a ground fault that caused the light to act that way, or if it is a bad motion detector.
I bypassed the motion detector and wired the black and white wires I installed directly to the lights and they work fine. I wonder if the motion sensor is not turning itself off completely, or if there are more significant problems.
I tested other outlets in the house with the ohm meter. I put one pin into the large neutral slot of the outlet and the other pin to the conduit or metal jct box and found the same connection between the neutral side of the outlet and the conduit.

Comment: The main panel has a main bonding jumper bonding the grounding and grounded conductor together. Metal conduit and boxes are grounded too.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the integral photo-cell or IR sensor, they are just switches and the half bright flickering sounds like a cycling switch. I hate to assume but if you bought it at a "big box" store take it back and don't ask for an exchange. Get a commercial quality unit from your nearest elect. supply house.

Comment: If you are not expecting to find a direct connection between Neutral and Ground you need to do more self-education before you go around doing electrical work.

Comment: Using an ohm meter on a live circuit even ground to neutral is a quick way to need a new ohm meter.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is about an electrician doing work on someone else's property, not a DIY.

Answer (score -1):

I’ve solved the problem once and for all without adding resistance (load) which defeat the purpose of energy saving. All i did is add a AC/AC relay in between the supply and the load to siphon any stray current and delay effect which causes the flickering. you can see attached picture[image]

Comment: this is a test trial to ensure it works without flickering.  Proven success.  Now i will install into actual site

Comment: I don't see how this is better than simply buying a better switch.

Comment: Is this an LED light?

Comment: I think the problem is that motion sensor switch doesn't really cuts off like a mechanical switch hence there are stray current residing in the circuit.  LED which is an low energy device gets affected by this effect and would either hold a low glow or would flicker.  Calculating the necessary resistance and loading the circuit to counter this effect would be counter power saving and troublesome.  What i did was connect a relay to the motion sensor.  So the motion sensor trigger the relay instead of the lights itself.

Comment: So the motion sensor trigger the relay instead of the lights itself.   The relay which is a mechanical switch, then turns the lighting circuit on/off.  This way the side effect of the motion sensor/LED is eradicated.  So this setup would help with any flickering problems with motion sensors and any light type.  Motion sensor quality may not help in this case.

Comment: I will take a SWAG and say it is a LED light bulb connected to a non compatible sensor. Replace the bulb with a tungsten bulb and if the flickering stops you have found the problem. You need a different motion sensor. You can buy a lot of electricity for the cost of the relay replacement that the bulb will use.